# Add SideBar/Widgets Just Below the Post

Tags: plugins, theme-development, widgets, register-sidebar

I have created and registered side bar in function.php and using it another place. It's working fine. Now I like to use it just below the post. I have installed some plugins -Bookmarks, related post...etc. They are also coming just below post. I want to show first the sidebar then the plugins.

If I put code just after

```
the_content();
```

It appears after plugins, but I have to show before plugins.

Let me know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Theory is simple - you just hook onto the **the_content** filter with a priority higher, then that of other plugin handlers:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'insert_my_sidebar', 9);
```

And then in **insert_my_sidebar** function you insert your sidebar.

But there is a caveat - actually not only user plugins, but also default filters have priority of 10. So by default there is no way to differentiate between them. You will have to implicitly unset default filters and re-set them with a priority higher then that of yours.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

And then:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize', 8        );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies', 8    );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars', 8      );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'  , 8          );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 8  );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment', 8 );
```

And you obviously should do that in **the_content** filter with even higher priority, like 7 :)

**UPDATE**:

Complete example:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepare_to_insert_my_sidebar', 7);

function prepare_to_insert_my_sidebar($content)
{
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize', 8        );
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies', 8    );
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars', 8      );
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'  , 8          );
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 8  );
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment', 8 );

    add_filter('the_content', 'insert_my_sidebar', 9);

    return $content;
}


function insert_my_sidebar($content)
{
    ob_start();
    dynamic_sidebar('name_of_your_sidebar');
    $content .= ob_get_clean();

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: make sure you return the $content in your insert_my_sidebar

Comment: plz give me sample insert_my_sidebar bcoz it should return string, how can we get sidebar as string?

Comment: dynamic_sidebar returns boolean true/false, not working.

Comment: Hmm... right. But anyway... it is the function you actually need. I updated example.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!